# How can I create a method that can intelligently create or update an entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am currently experiencing the following error with Entity Framework Core 6:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'PromiseRecord' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ID'} is already being tracked. When attachi
> ng existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

The intent of the following function is to reduce code duplication and create a method that can either create or update an existing entity. I based my implementation off the following resource https://entityframework.net/add-or-update. The initial record creation works however I receive the error described above when updating an existing record. Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?

```
public async Task<Promise?> SavePromiseAsync(Promise promise)
{
    var promiseRecord = new PromiseRecord
    {
        ID = promise.ID,
        LovedOneRecordID = promise.LovedOneID,
        Description = promise.Description,
        CompletedAt = promise.CompletedAt,
        DueBy = promise.DueBy
    };

    _context.Entry(promiseRecord).State = promise.ID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return MapPromise(promiseRecord);
}
```

I have verified using the debugger that domain model is passed in correctly with the proper ID and other related data.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your context already have an instance of `PromiseRecord` with the same ID as the new `PromiseRecord` you build and attach there to the context. You might want to read the existing `PromiseRecord` instance and change it or ensure that there is no existing instance in the context you are working in/with.

Comment: Detach the entity, before changing it's state. Also, use `Add` or `Update`/`Attach`, instead of changing it's state, directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your dbContext already has an entity with the specified ID and you can't add second entity with the same ID. If you really need to insert a new entity or update it if you have an existing one you can use [this library](https://github.com/artiomchi/FlexLabs.Upsert) to UpSert an entity:

```
await _context.PromiseRecords
    .Upsert(new PromiseRecord
    {
        LovedOneRecordID = promise.LovedOneID,
        Description = promise.Description,
        CompletedAt = promise.CompletedAt,
        DueBy = promise.DueBy
    })
    .On(v => v.ID)
    .WhenMatched(v => new PromiseRecord
    {
        LovedOneRecordID = promise.LovedOneID,
        Description = promise.Description,
        CompletedAt = promise.CompletedAt,
        DueBy = promise.DueBy
    })
    .RunAsync();
```